# Three.js: The Surface is One-Sided

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

This code (three.js):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
init();
animate();

// FUNCTIONS        
function init() 
{
// SCENE
scene = new THREE.Scene();
// CAMERA
var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth, SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
var VIEW_ANGLE = 45, ASPECT = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, NEAR = 0.1, FAR = 20000;
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR);
scene.add(camera);
camera.position.set(0,150,400);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);  
// RENDERER
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {antialias:true} );
renderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
container = document.createElement( 'div' );
document.body.appendChild( container );
container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
// EVENTS

// CONTROLS
controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );
// STATS
stats = new Stats();
stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
stats.domElement.style.bottom = '0px';
stats.domElement.style.zIndex = 100;
container.appendChild( stats.domElement );
// LIGHT
var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
light.position.set(0,250,0);
scene.add(light);
// FLOOR
var floorTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'https://localhost/geos/images/square.png' );
floorTexture.wrapS = floorTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping; 
floorTexture.repeat.set( 10, 10 );
var floorMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: floorTexture } );
var floorGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1000, 1000, 10, 10);
var floor = new THREE.Mesh(floorGeometry, floorMaterial);
floor.position.y = -0.5;
floor.doubleSided = true;
scene.add(floor);
}

function animate() 
{
   requestAnimationFrame( animate );
   render();       
   update();
}

function update()
{


   controls.update();
   stats.update();
}

function render() 
{
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

</script>
```

Render passes, all right, but when I try to look under the surface it disappears. But in an example of which is taken from the code works correctly. The only difference: in the example library r49, but I have a r55

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of

```
floor.doubleSided = true;
```

use

```
floorMaterial.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
```

If you are learning, only refer to the official three.js examples, which work with r.55.

If you must update from an older version, see the [Migration Wiki](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration) for help upgrading.